# Is there a way to hide the RRP/Old Price on Magento for specific customer groups?

Tags: javascript, php, magento, web, e-commerce

I need to hide the RRP/Old Price on Magento for just one of the customer groups on the store - is there a way I can display none the price if a certain customer group member is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding an update to `catalog/product/price.phtml` to add a containing div with the current customer group as a class / reference so that you can add CSS to display none.  Alternatively, you could actually wrap the code in this logic.

```
$customerGroupId= Mage::getSingleton("customer/session")->getCustomerGroupId();
```

Will get you the Group ID of the current customer session (remember, Magento tracks "Not logged in", so this should always return something).  You could then echo a class like this onto `price-box` or a wrapping div

```
class="customer-group-<?php echo $customerGroupId;?>"
```